# Weight Decay in Neural Neural Networks Weight Update and Convergence

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, convergence

I have a neural network (That I created using java) for a class assignment that is working when I do not use any weight decay value, but when I use a value greater than or equal to .001, my accuracy drops greatly.  The data is normalized. I am not sure if it is how I am calculating  the convergence condition, or if my weight updates with weight decay is incorrect. I am using a sigmoid activation function. My classifier is binary 0 or 1, and when classifying if my output is > .5, the example is 1, and <= .5, the example is 0.

In my test I am using 5 hidden neurons + 1 bias, and 11 input neruons + 1 bias, and 1 output neuron. When running with 0 weight decay i am getting 99% accuracy, however when i use a value of .001 I am getting 56% accuracy. The accuracy I am using is TP + TN / (TP + TN + FP + FN)

My weight update right now is

Weight = Weight - LearningRate * WeightChange - Weight * WeightDecay

My convergence test is if the absolute difference in the sum of the current weights and the sum of the previous weights is < 0.00001 I say that the network has converged. Is this correct in thinking so?

Let me know if there is any more information needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not surprising that weight decay will hurt performance of your neural network at some point. Let the prediction loss of your net be $\mathcal{L}$ and the weight decay loss $\mathcal{R}$. Given a coefficient $\lambda$ that establishes a tradeoff between the two, one optimises
$$
\mathcal{L} + \lambda \mathcal{R}.
$$
At the optimium of this loss, the gradients of both terms will have to sum up to zero:
$$
\triangledown \mathcal{L} = -\lambda \triangledown \mathcal{R}.
$$
This makes clear that we will not be at an optimium of the training loss. Even more so, the higher $\lambda$ the steeper the gradient of $\mathcal{L}$, which in the case of convex loss functions implies a higher distance from the optimum.